# Pre-cache an initial query, to have sub-queries not hit the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have two tables, `Users` and `Responses`, where there are many responses per user. I'm looking to do some computation on the set of responses for each user. Something like the code below:

```
all_users = User.all
all_rs = Responses.all

all_users.map { |u| all_rs.where(user: u).count }
```

As written this will make a call to the database for each user. Is there a way to pre-cache the `all_rs` data, so that each subsequent `where` is done in memory?

The logic above could probably be easily written in sql, but imagine that the code in the map block contained a lot more work.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is **counter cache** (see section 4.1.2.3 of [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)).

To enable counter cache, first, add or change your migration file:

**db/migrate/add_counter_cache_to_users.rb**

```
class AddCounterCacheToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # Counter cache field
    add_column :users, :responses_count, :integer, null: false, default: 0
    # Optionally add index to the column if you want to `order by` it.
    add_index :users, :responses_cache
  end
end
```

Then modify your model classes

**app/models/response.rb**

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
end
```

Run `rake db:migrate`. From now on, whenever a `Response` is created, the value of `users.responses_count` column will automatically increment by 1, and whenever a `Response` is destroyed, that column's value will decrement by 1.

If you want the count of someone's responses, just call `responses_count` on that user.

```
user = User.first
user.responses_count  #=> the responses count of the user
# or
user.responses.size
```

Your original requirement can be fulfilled with

```
User.select(:responses_count).to_a
```

## UPDATE

I can't think how can I have missed such a bloody easy solution

```
Response.group(:user_id).count
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
responses_by_user = Response.all.group_by(&:user_ud)
```

(assuming that Response has a `user_id` attribute)

You could then do `responses_by_user[user.id]` to get the responses for a user without any further queries. Do be careful of the overhead of creating all these extra ActiveRecord objects. As you hint, the very specific example you give can be handled by an sql group/count, which would probably be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe ? assuming users has_many responses

```
all_users = User.includes(:responses)
user_responses_count = all_users.map { |u| u.responses.count }
```

this will not query for responses 1000 times, in cases you have 1000 users. Let me know if this works for your use-case.

Note that this query level caching. No model changes are required..

Comment: It will do a query per user - `count` always executes a count query, even if the data is loaded. You may be thinking of `size`